# Defining a new command, the output of which depends on an internal parameter

Tags: macros, definition

Maybe someone can tell me how to define a new command in \LaTeX, which can take one mandatory value and another optional value (parameter) as input. In this case, depending on the value of the optional argument, the type of the output object should change.

Specifically in my case, I need to specify a command `\dependSet(<arg>, <opt par>)` to draw parentheses. in this case, depending on the presence / absence of the optional argument should change the output (presence / absence of a vertical line inside):

| Function | Output |
| --- | --- |
| `\dependSet{x, y}` | [image] |
| `\dependSet{x, y}{a}` | [image: row] |

Accordingly, for usability it is important that the parameter comes after the arguments of the command, and it is selected with curly brackets, not square ones.

**P.S.:** Actually, it's a pity that LaTex uses a rather uncomfortable notation (which reeks of something like ALGOL 60) and does nothing to make it possible to define new commands in Python-like style.

Comment: Did you check https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros and https://www.ctan.org/topic/macro-supp ?

Comment: optional argument would be in `[]` not `{}` but with regard to your PS do you mean optional  named arguments as in the standard `\includegraphics[width=2cm,angle=90]{filename}` ?

Comment: You _could_ define the optional argument with `{` but usability is negatively impacted and it is strongly recommended that you avoid that. (You have to explicitly load `xparse` to enable the deprecated `g` argument type)

Comment: How about defining a command that uses `\dependSet{x,y}` for your first and `\dependSet[x,y]{a}` for your second input case?

Comment: **@MS-SPO**, yes, I looked at the documentation on the relevant issues, and still came to _Stack_. )))

**@David Carlisle**, To be honest, I don't really like the use of `xparse`. I would try to defer the possibility of using this library directly to a last resort.

Comment: **Skillmon**, still, the idea is to use this command after functions to denote arguments and parameters, e.g. `f\dependSet{x}` -> `f(x)`, and when an additional parameter is required, you could just write `f\dependSet{x}{t}` -> `f(x | t)`. That is, as it seems to me, the syntax should always be preserved and be clear.

Comment: @Sssur sorry, but that syntax isn't clear, it is problematic. If you have an optional argument use the conventional style of optional arguments, that is `[]`. I don't see how your `\dependSet{x}{t}` should be clearer than `\dependSet{x}[t]`.

Comment: And if you want an easy way to set up a command with `key=value` syntax, there are solutions for that (I think my `expkv-cs` does a pretty good job providing an easy interface with `\ekvcSplit`, though it isn't as flexible as Python would be (no positional arguments, just kw)).

Comment: IMHO, most clear syntax is: `(x,y)` or `(x,y|a)`. First case needs 5 characters, second case needs 7 characters in our source file. On the other hand you suggest syntax `\dependSet{x,y}` or `\dependSet{x,y}{a}`. First case needs 15 characters and second case 18 characters in your source file. Why this complication? We can do a macro which transforms a complicated syntax to a clear syntax, but why to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's assume you don't want to type in `(x,y)` or `(x,y\mid a)` for some reasons. And there are good reasons not to: for instance, you might want or be required to change notation. A hardwired input would make the task very difficult.

The idea is to type in

```
\dependSet{x,y}
\dependSet{x,y|a}
```

but without impacting on the final output. The input is quite natural and avoids the complications of too many braces.

How do we do it? We can use `\NewDocumentCommand` and its `\SplitArgument` feature.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{xparse} % uncomment for older versions of LaTeX

\NewDocumentCommand{\dependSet}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{|}}m}{%
  \dependSetAux#1%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\dependSetAux}{mm}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}{% no | found
    (#1)%
  }{% found |
    (#1\mid #2)%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

$\dependSet{x}+\dependSet{x,y}+\dependSet{x,y|a}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Comments.**

The command `\dependSet` passes its argument to `\dependSetAux` as two braced groups. If there is no `|` in the initial argument, the second braced group will be `{-NoValue-}` that can be tested as shown.

If you want to change the final formatting, act on `\dependSetAux`.

A possibly more efficient code, but less straightforward, would be

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\dependSetAux}{mm}{%
  (#1\IfValueT{#2}{\mid #2})%
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `\dependSetAux` not be defined via `\NewDocumentCommand`, after all it is an auxiliary, not at the document level.

Comment: @Skillmon The auxiliary command might need preprocessing itself, and it’s more friendly doing like this rather than going `\ExplSyntaxOn` anyway, for such a simple task.

Comment: Thanks a lot! True, a natural question arose (_which I had not even thought about before_) how do `\def`, `\newcommand`, `\NewDocumentCommand` etc differ?

Comment: @Sssur `\def` is dangerous; `\newcommand` has just a few features; `\NewDocumentCommand` has many, see `texdoc xparse`

Answer (score 4):

The following code is fully compatible with your specification, given by complete example:

```
\documentclass[onecolumn]{article}

\newcommand\ds[1]{%
    (#1)%
}

\begin{document}
    This can be used as text:
    
    \ds{x, y}
    
    \ds{x, y|a}
    
    It can also be used inline in math-mode: $\ds{x, y}$, see also: $\ds{x, y|a}$.
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the idea is to separate argument from functionality. This is easier than thinking of all kinds of combinations you may or may not want to use.

[image]